# Is this a gcc 11 compiler bug with C++20 concepts, or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm experimenting with C++20 concepts, using my own local build of a clone of the GCC 11 source code.  I'm getting compilation errors from GCC that seem wrong to me.  I've reduced my code triggering the diagnostic to what's below, with the GCC command line to compile it and the full resulting diagnostic output below that.

For focus, the particular section of the diagnostic output that seems wrong to me is

```
repro.cpp:9:13: note: the required expression ‘flequal(a, b)’ is invalid, because
    9 |     {flequal(a, b)} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
      |      ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
repro.cpp:9:13: error: ‘flequal’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
repro.cpp:22:6: note: ‘template<class auto:1, class auto:2>  requires (Flequalable<auto:1>) && (Flequalable<auto:2>) bool flequal(const Bar<auto:1>&, const Bar<auto:2>&)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
   22 | bool flequal(Bar<Flequalable auto> const &a, Bar<Flequalable auto> const &b) {
      |      ^~~~~~~
```

It says the candidate function was declared later in the translation unit than the point of instantiation, but that is not true, at least going by source line order in my code snippet.

**Is this build error wrong, or am I doing something wrong in my use of C++20 concepts?**

Note the variant, in a comment at the end of the code, which compiles without any diagnostic.

Code:

```
#include <concepts>

using std::floating_point;

template< typename T >
concept Flequalable
    = floating_point<T>
    && requires(T a, T b) {
        {flequal(a, b)} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    };

template<floating_point T>
bool flequal( T a, T b) {
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
struct Bar {
    T t;
};

bool flequal(Bar<Flequalable auto> const &a, Bar<Flequalable auto> const &b) {
    return true;
}

bool foo() {
    Bar<double> a = {2.0};
    Bar<double> b = {3.0};
    return flequal(a, b); // Causes diagnostic
    // return flequal(a.t, b.t); // This works
}
```

Compilation command-line:

```
/usr/local/gcc-11-master/bin/g++-11 -c repro.cpp -o repro.o -std=c++20 -fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=5 2> diagnostic.txt
```

Full GCC diagnostic:

```
repro.cpp: In function ‘bool foo()’:
repro.cpp:29:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘flequal(Bar<double>&, Bar<double>&)’
   29 |     return flequal(a, b); // Causes diagnostic
      |                        ^
repro.cpp:13:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class T>  requires  floating_point<T> bool flequal(T, T)’
   13 | bool flequal( T a, T b) {
      |      ^~~~~~~
repro.cpp:13:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
repro.cpp:13:6: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from repro.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-11-master/include/c++/11.0.1/concepts: In substitution of ‘template<class T>  requires  floating_point<T> bool flequal(T, T) [with T = Bar<double>]’:
repro.cpp:29:24:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-11-master/include/c++/11.0.1/concepts:111:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘floating_point<T>’ [with T = Bar<double>]
/usr/local/gcc-11-master/include/c++/11.0.1/concepts:111:30: note: the expression ‘is_floating_point_v<_Tp> [with _Tp = Bar<double>]’ evaluated to ‘false’
  111 |     concept floating_point = is_floating_point_v<_Tp>;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
repro.cpp:22:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class auto:1, class auto:2>  requires (Flequalable<auto:1>) && (Flequalable<auto:2>) bool flequal(const Bar<auto:1>&, const Bar<auto:2>&)’
   22 | bool flequal(Bar<Flequalable auto> const &a, Bar<Flequalable auto> const &b) {
      |      ^~~~~~~
repro.cpp:22:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
repro.cpp:22:6: note: constraints not satisfied
repro.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class auto:1, class auto:2>  requires (Flequalable<auto:1>) && (Flequalable<auto:2>) bool flequal(const Bar<auto:1>&, const Bar<auto:2>&) [with auto:1 = double; auto:2 = double]’:
repro.cpp:29:24:   required from here
repro.cpp:6:9:   required for the satisfaction of ‘Flequalable<auto:1>’ [with auto:1 = double]
repro.cpp:8:8:   in requirements with ‘T a’, ‘T b’ [with T = double]
repro.cpp:9:13: note: the required expression ‘flequal(a, b)’ is invalid, because
    9 |     {flequal(a, b)} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
      |      ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
repro.cpp:9:13: error: ‘flequal’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
repro.cpp:22:6: note: ‘template<class auto:1, class auto:2>  requires (Flequalable<auto:1>) && (Flequalable<auto:2>) bool flequal(const Bar<auto:1>&, const Bar<auto:2>&)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
   22 | bool flequal(Bar<Flequalable auto> const &a, Bar<Flequalable auto> const &b) {
      |      ^~~~~~~
```

Here's the exact GCC version information:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/gcc-11-master/bin/g++-11
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/gcc-11-master/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-11-master --program-suffix=-11 --enable-libstdcxx-debug : (reconfigured) ../gcc/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-11-master --program-suffix=-11 --enable-libstdcxx-debug
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 11.0.1 20210304 (experimental) (GCC)
```

Comment: *the point of instantiation* is a tricky concept. Seems you and the compiler has different ideas of where that is in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `Bar<Flequalable auto>` is not valid syntax. You can have a top-level variable declared like `Concept auto v` but you can't nest that within templates. So it really should be:

```cpp
template <Flequalable T, Flequalable U>
bool flequal(Bar<T> const &a, Bar<U> const &b) {
    return true;
}
```

Now, what happens when we try to call `flequal(a, b)`. We deduce `T=double` and `U=double` and then try to evaluate if `double` satisfies `Flequalable`. `double` is `floating_point`, so we keep going to check the requirement that `flequal(a, b)` is a valid expression for two `double`s.

This is unqualified lookup, so we first do regular unqualified lookup for the name `flequal`. It's important to keep in mind that this lookup happens from the point of the *concept definition*, not from the point where it is used. That is, we're looking up from here:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

using std::floating_point;

template< typename T >
concept Flequalable
    = floating_point<T>
    && requires(T a, T b) {
        {flequal(a, b)} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;  // <== here!
    };
```

Not where the concept is used:

```cpp
template <Flequalable T, Flequalable U> // <== not here
bool flequal(Bar<T> const &a, Bar<U> const &b) {
    return true;
}
```

Nor where the function template using the concept is invoked:

```cpp
return flequal(a, b); // <== not here either
```

We find nothing. There are no declarations of `flequal` visible from that point. Then, we do argument-dependent lookup. `double` has *no* associated namespaces, so this *also* trivially finds nothing. As such, there are zero candidates, so `double` does not satisfy `Flequalable`.

In order to make this work, you have to make sure that unqualified lookup in the concept `Flequalable` actually finds your `flequal` function. Just swap the two declarations, and then everything works fine.

---

This makes it seem like `flequal` is some kind of customization point, but there are only a fixed number of `floating_point` types (`float`, `double`, `long double`, and cv-qualified versions thereof) so I'm not entirely sure what the point here is.

Comment: I think it would help avoid confusion if you were a bit more explicit that the unqualified name lookup we're performing for `flequal` happens in the context of the concept definition, not in the context of the function template definition or even the context of the callsite in `main`. In fact, this may be one of those rare occurrences where it might help the user to better understand if we point out that unqualified name lookup actually occurs when compiling template definitions.

Comment: I had begun a comment asking if my confusion could be that I'm expecting the concept requirements to be checked down where the call to 'fequal(a,b)' occurs down inside foo(), so I'm confused when the diagnostic says, "requirement fails because flequal(double,double) doesn't occur till later int eh translation unit".  Does unqualified lookup mean that at the point the concept requirements are actually being defined, there has not yet been any declaration of flequal(double,double)?

Comment: As to the bit about whether flequal is a customization point--I'm not sure it fits what a customization point really is.  And since the code here is a minimized example in order to trigger the diagnostic, combined from a header and a .cpp, it might not convey the intent.  But my plan for flequal is for a way to compare floating point numbers, as well as any larger classes whose comparisons will eventually boil down to floating point comparisons.  In my mind, flequal is a project-wide operation, which will be overloaded for new classes where they are defined.

Comment: @Barry, when I swap the definitions for `concept Flequalable` and `template<floating_point T> bool flequal(T,T)`, it will build, like you said.

But GCC is then accepting `bool flequal(Bar<Flequalable auto> const &a, Bar<Flequalable auto> const &b)`, which you said is invalid syntax.  Is that a GCC bug then?  If I drop the `auto`, but not add the preamble `template<Flequalable T, ...`, the compiler says

`repro.cpp:23:18: error: expected ‘auto’ or ‘decltype(auto)’ after ‘Flequalable’
   23 | bool flequal(Bar<Flequalable> const &a, Bar<Flequalable> const &b) { ...`